# How to use the Envelope F-Curve Modifier in Blender 2.93

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

I would think that defining a range of a minimum and maximum of f-curve values would take only 2 variables: your minimum and a maximum and that should be enough to scale the f-curves so that they are always between those values. In Blender 2.93 there are 6 needed: *Reference*, *Minimum*, *Maximum* all of which don't show any effect at all until you add a Control Point that comes with the variables *Frame* (which doesn't seem to have any influence on anything), *Minimum* (again?) and also again *Maximum*. I didn't understand the documentation so my question is pretty simple:

**Lets say I have an animation f-curve that ranges from -2 to 5. How would I need to use the envelope modifier to map it to 1 to 10?** And why are there so many variables needed? Isn't having to use this many parameters for such a simple task a little unhandy?